# Determinant of a tridiagonal matrix with constant values $5,3,2$ on the main, upper and lower diagonals

Tags: determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

Can you help me to compute determinant of matrix

$$A =\begin{pmatrix}
5 &3  &0  &\cdots   &0  &0 \\ 
 2&5  &3  &\cdots   &0  &0 \\ 
 0&2  &5  &\cdots   & 0 &0 \\ 
 \cdots & \cdots  &\cdots   & \cdots  &\cdots  &\cdots  \\ 
 0&0  &0  &\cdots   &\cdots   &3 \\ 
 0&  0& 0& \cdots  & 2  &5 
\end{pmatrix}$$

and dimension of $A$ is $n \times n$.

I don't know how to solve it !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Why the tag "symmetric matrix" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Actually, why any of the tags? I removed all except [tag:determinant] and added the most relevant one instead, [tag:tridiagonal-matrices].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant

Comment: Gerry Myerson: Thank you, I see

Comment: K.defaoite: Oh. that's general form, so great. Thank you!